# Ruby on Rails App not starting in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment, production-environment

Everything works fine in development mode, but when I try to start my app in production mode (RAILS_ENV=production script/server) I get the following error:

```
/opt/ruby1.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/searchlogic-2.4.19/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/conditions.rb:81:in `method_missing': protected method `scope' called for #<Class:0x7f41de524410> (NoMethodError)                                                                                               
        from /opt/ruby1.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/searchlogic-2.4.19/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/association_conditions.rb:19:in `method_missing' 
        from /opt/ruby1.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/searchlogic-2.4.19/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/association_ordering.rb:27:in `method_missing'   
        from /opt/ruby1.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/searchlogic-2.4.19/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/ordering.rb:30:in `method_missing'               
        from /opt/ruby1.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/searchlogic-2.4.19/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/or_conditions.rb:28:in `method_missing'          
        from /opt/ruby1.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1959:in `method_missing_without_paginate'           
        from /opt/ruby1.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/will_paginate-2.3.12/lib/will_paginate/finder.rb:170:in `method_missing'                         
        from /opt/ruby1.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/acts_as_commentable-3.0.0/lib/comment_methods.rb:12:in `included'                                
        from .../app/models/comment.rb:2:in `include'                                                           
        from .../app/models/comment.rb:2                                                                        
        from /opt/ruby1.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'                                          
        from /opt/ruby1.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'...
```

Now it seems to me it that the acts_as_commentable gem is causing this. But how come, it works fine in development mode.

Comment: show comment.rb (around line 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the error thanks to fl00r's comment:

> show comment.rb (around line 2)

Line 2 in comment.rb was `include ActsAsCommentable::Comment`. That seemed a bit strange to me, so I took a look at the official documentation for the acts_as_commentable gem. That was the problem. It should have been `acts_as_commentable` instead. Must have copy-pasted it from somewhere.

Still, the mystery remains how it could have worked in development mode. Because of the class caching mentioned by annaswims?

Answer (score 1):

in development mode classes are loaded as you need them.  In production, they're cached when rails starts.